# random internet latency issues

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, isp

We are having lag issues with our internet and have been for a while now. I have contacted our ISP's customer service SEVERAL times regarding the issue. Every time i talk to them they tell me to restart the modem and all of our routers. I do that and it does not fix the problem.

Then they say there are too many people on the internet in your area right now. Using all the bandwidth. Excuse.

They have sent a few people out to diagnose the issue and it is still not resolved. We had one guy show up and check the lights and then left saying that it was just too many people logged on. All he did was look at the lights. >=(

---

I am paying for ~15MB down and roughly ~2MB up.

Here is what i am getting and my setup.

**NOTE:** *When using their speedtest service, i am getting around 8-13MB down. But when i use speakeasy speedtest or any other speedtest service i am getting really low numbers to places like chicago, atlanta, dallas, washington. I live in Alabama.*

```
SETUP1
```

Their modem. I have a router connected to the modem and then another router (setup to act as a switch) connected to that router. The second router is used a switch for 3 desktop computers (for gaming). We also have a bluray player and smart tv wireless. (Not on while gaming, but they seem to think that matters o.^).

With this setup we are seeing around ~2MB down. This happens randomly. We will have around ~5-7MB down most of the time. But probably around 4-5 times a week we will have a few hours of less than 2MB down. The only time we play is in the evening, so it is the only time we notice. Even at good times we are still only getting like half of what they promise and we are paying for... i have talked to them about this and they dont seem to care.

---

```
SETUP2
```

Their modem. I connect directly to the modem with a laptop during these times of bad connection and i am still seeing around 2MB down. But they claim nothing wrong when they run their tests.

---

I live in an apartment complex that supposedly has a contract with them that forces us to get this specific isp.

- What is the issue?
- Can i demand them to fix the issue?
- Would buying a new modem (of my own) fix the issue?
- Anyway that i can get a different isp in my complex?

It is becoming unbearable. And their customer service is no help.

Thanks

Comment: The primary reason for this kind of low throughput (if you really have a 15Mbps contract) is usually packet loss.  You need to use [`mtr`](http://winmtr.net/) and trace your loss to one of your ISP's download points for a sustained period of time to isolate where the loss is occuring.  It is entirely possible that the problem is inside your apartment.  Please post [`winmtr`](http://winmtr.net/) packet loss results after a few hours.  Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427787/why-tcp-not-recved-ack-from-server-in-solaris-machine/8428761#8428761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buying my own modem fixed the issue.

Them giving me a new modem, did not.